# The url of the image uploaded from json is not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am downloading json from the server and I need to see part of its data data in tile format.
I wrote a small website that allows you to do this, but I ran into the problem that the images are not loaded.
[image: text]

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <style></style>
  <body>
    <div class="weapons"></div>
  </div>
  <script async="" src="./js/main.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {margin: 20px;padding: 20px;font-family: "Droid Sans";background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);}
  a {text-decoration: none;color: inherit;}
  .main {position: sticky;top: 10px;right: 1vw;background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);padding: 10px;color: rgb(0, 0, 0);border-radius: 5px;}
  .weapon-category {display: flex;}
  .weapon-category p {font-weight: bold;font-size: 0.9vw;}
  .weapon-item {flex: 1;max-width: 100%;background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);margin: 3px;display: inline-block;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;border-radius: 10px;}
  .weapon-item p { text-align: center;}
  .weapon-item img {display: block;margin: 0 auto;max-width:90%;margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

```js
import { weapon_list } from './weapons.mjs';

const normalize =(_) => _.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');

const handleWeapon = (data) => {
  gtaConsole.style.color = '#fff';
  gtaConsole.value += `${data.name}, ${data.image};\n`;
};

const weaponDom = document.querySelector('div.weapons');
for(const category in weapon_list) {
  const id = normalize(category);
  weaponDom.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<h3>${category}</h3>
<div id="${id}" class="weapon-category">
</div>
<hr>
`);

  const categoryDom = document.querySelector('#' + id);
  weapon_list[category].map(weapon => {
    const id = normalize(weapon.name);
    categoryDom.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<div class="weapon-item" id="${id}" data-name="${weapon.name}" data-image="${weapon.img}">
  <p>${weapon.name}</p>
  <img src="${weapon.img}">
</div>
`);
  });
}
```

```
export const weapon_list = {
    'item' : [
         {
            "amount": 1,
            'img': "https://i.imgur.com/SGyP257.png",
            "name": "40-процентный раствор Глюкоза - 14 ампул",
            "weight": 0.01
         }],
};
```

I tested these links on w3schools and the link works fine there if you insert src directly into html.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are going to add the title and image both via JS code using the **categoryDom**

And the categoryDom is pointing to the element having html id and using that categoryDom you are not able to add entire html as it not able to get the element value with insertAdjacentHTML method here.

In return we are getting the element value null in the output of categoryDom object, Do check your console it must be throwing error like,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'insertAdjacentHTML')

So try getting the element and then add the html elements.

Comment: no, there is no such mistake